# Should I recreate the EAGL context when handling an handleScreenDidConnectNotification?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, eaglcontext

I am attempting to handle handleScreenDid(Dis)ConnectNotification's in iOS. The problem I have is that I get an error of GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION from non-specific glFunctions() in my application 2 frames after handling a handleScreenDidConnectNotification.

I am already deleting and recreating my framebuffers and renderbuffers (because obviously the resolution is changing) from the notification. But not the EAGLContext.

My question is: do I need to release/delete the EAGLContext* when handling the notification and I guess also delete then recreate all of my gl resources?